# Redis : Can't handle RDB format version 9 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, redis

Following the indications in here: [Redis-QuickStart](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart) I installed in my Ubuntu 18.04.01 Server Edition the latest stable Redis release : [download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz)
and tested the result of the compilation:

```
\o/ All tests passed without errors!
```

As suggested, I copied redis-server and redis-cli into /usr/local/bin:

```
marco@pc01:~/redis-stable$ sudo cp src/redis-server /usr/local/bin/
marco@pc01:~/redis-stable$ sudo cp src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/
```

But when just executing the redis-server binary it says it can't handle RDB format version 9

````
marco@pc01:~$ redis-server
11700:C 18 Apr 08:18:52.007 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
11700:C 18 Apr 08:18:52.007 # Redis version=4.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, 
pid=11700, just started
11700:C 18 Apr 08:18:52.007 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In 
order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
11700:M 18 Apr 08:18:52.007 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was 
originally set to 1024).
                _._
           _.-``__ ''-._
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 4.0.9 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 11700
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'
          `-._        _.-'
              `-.__.-'

11700:M 18 Apr 08:18:52.008 # Server initialized
11700:M 18 Apr 08:18:52.008 # Can't handle RDB format version 9
11700:M 18 Apr 08:18:52.008 # Fatal error loading the DB: Invalid argument. Exiting.
````

Searching for some hints I found this : [Can't handle RDB format version 8](https://github.com/alexdicianu/redis_toolkit/issues/14)
whose solution was to use the lastest version of redis.
But I downloaded the latest stable release of Redis!!!
So... how to solve the problem?

Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco

As said in the comment below, I SOLVED the problem by deleting /home/marco/dump.rdb file.

Comment: SOLVED: removed /home/marco/dump.rdb file. And the fatal error disappeared!!

Comment: In my case the dump.rdb was not in the home directory, but I ran a 'locate dump.rdb' and deleted it and the problem went away!